# Delay animation until other animation is complete (sliding content(

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have this code which animates between divs sliding out. If an item is clicked, it's relevant content slides out. If another item is clicked, the current content slides back in and the new content slides out.

However,

```
var lastClicked = null;
var animateClasses = ['ale', 'bramling', 'bullet', 'miami-weisse'];
   for (var i=0; i<animateClasses.length; i++) {
      (function(animCls) { 
      $('.each-brew.'+animCls).toggle(function() {
    if (lastClicked && lastClicked != this) {
        // animate it back
        $(lastClicked).trigger('click');
    }
    lastClicked = this;
    $('.each-brew-content.'+animCls).show().animate({ left: '0' }, 1000).css('position','inherit');
      }, function() {
           $('.each-brew-content.'+animCls)
                  .animate({ left: '-33.3333%' }, 1000, function() { $(this).hide()})  // hide the element in the animation on-complete callback
                  .css('position','relative'); 
      });
      })(animateClasses[i]);  //  self calling anonymous function
   }
```

However, the content sliding out once the already open content slides back is sliding out too quickly - it needs to wait until the content has fully slided back in before it slides out. Is this possible?

Here's a link to what I'm currently working on to get an idea (http://goo.gl/s8Tl6).

Cheers in advance,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on it as a drop-in replacement with no markup changes. You want one of three things to happen when a menu item is clicked:

1. if the clicked item is currently showing, hide it
2. if something else is showing, hide it, then show the current item's content
3. if nothing is showing, show the current item's content

---

```
var lastClicked = null;
// here lastClicked points to the currently visible content
var animateClasses = ['ale', 'bramling', 'bullet', 'miami-weisse'];
   for (var i=0; i<animateClasses.length; i++) {
      (function(animCls) {
          $('.each-brew.'+animCls).click(function(event){
              if(lastClicked && lastClicked == animCls){
                  // if the lastClicked is `this` then just hide the content
                  $('.each-brew-content.'+animCls).animate(
                                          { left: '-33.3333%' }, 1000,
                                          function() {
                                              $(this).hide();
                                          }).css('position','relative');
                  lastClicked = null;
              }else{
                  if(lastClicked){
                      // if something else is lastClicked, hide it,
                      //then trigger a click on the new target
                      $('.each-brew-content.'+lastClicked).animate(
                                          { left: '-33.3333%' }, 1000,
                                          function() {
                                              $(this).hide();
                                              $(event.target).trigger('click');
                                          }).css('position','relative');
                      lastClicked = null;
                  }else{
                      // if there is no currently visible div,
                      // show our content
                      $('.each-brew-content.'+animCls).show()
                                        .animate({ left: '0' }, 1000)
                                        .css('position','relative');
                    lastClicked = animCls;
                  }
              }
          });
      })(animateClasses[i]);  //  self calling anonymous function
   }
```

Comment: Chris, this worked a treat. Thanks for the solution - I will dig around and make sure I understand it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm pretty sure there are other more easy possibilities and I didn't have much time but here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uaNKz/

Basicly you use the `callback` function to wait until the animation is complete. In this special case it's the `complete: function(){...}`

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $('#ale').click(function(){
        if ($('div').hasClass('toggled')){
          $('.toggled').animate({ width: "toggle" }, { duration:250, complete: function(){
            $('#alecont').animate({ width: "toggle" }, { duration:250 }).addClass('toggled');}
          }).removeClass('toggled');
        }else{
          $('#alecont').animate({ width: "toggle" }, { duration:250 }).addClass('toggled');
        }
    });
  $('#bramling').click(function(){
    if ($('div').hasClass('toggled')){
      $('.toggled').animate({ width: "toggle" }, { duration:250, complete: function(){
        $('#bramcont').animate({ width: "toggle" }, { duration:250 }).addClass('toggled');}
      }).removeClass('toggled');
    }else{
      $('#bramcont').animate({ width: "toggle" }, { duration:250 }).addClass('toggled');
    }
  });
});
```

I give a `toggled` class if a div is expanded. Since the animation on your page seems to be pretty much broken I think this would be a better way to do this. But remember: my code isn't really good. Just fast and it can be refactored. It's working tho..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using toggles, bind an on "click" handler to your ".each-brew" divs.  In the handler, first hide content divs and then show the appropriate content when that animation completes.  You can do that with either a promise or a callback.  Something like this...

```
 $(".each-brew").on("click", function (event) {
      $(".each-brew-content").show().animate({ left: "0" }, 1000, function() {
          // Get the brew name from the class list. 
          // This assumes that the brew is the second class in the list, as in your markup.
          var brew = event.currentTarget.className.split(/\s+/)[1];
          $(".each-brew-content." + brew).animate({ left: "-33.3333%" }, 1000, function() { $(this).hide(); });
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an event and observer would do the trick for you.

set up the callback function on completion of your animation to fire an event.

the listener would first listen for any animation event and after that event is triggered listen for the completion event. when the completion event is fired execute the initial animation event.run method (or whatever you would want to call it)

Within the listener 
on newanimationeventtriger(new_anim) wait for x seconds (to eliminate infinite loop poss) while if this lastevent triggers done == true{
new_anim.run();
}

Comment: This might help https://tutsplus.com/lesson/custom-events-and-the-observer-pattern/